# Rock Paper Scissors not working

Tags: python, loops

I have a game of Rock Paper Scissors with an AI that learns from you by trying everything until it gets a good algorithm, but my code stops working as soon as the AI gets a point, can someone help?

```
import random
print "Rock. Paper. Scissors. Awesome, a quick project made by me"

a = ["R", "P", "S"]
Ai = 0
Player = 0
samples = ['R']
l = 't'
c = random.choice(a)
play = 0
rndm = ['r.c', '+', '-']
count = 0
max = len(samples)
it = 0

def learn():

    global rndm
    global samples
    global Ai
    global Player
    global l
    global play
    global c
    global max
    global it

    number = random.randint(1,5)

    if l == 'p':
        #Random Learning
        choice = random.choice(rndm)
        if choice == "-":
            choicetwo = random.randint(0,len(samples))
            if choicetwo == len(samples):
                choicetwo -= 1
            samples.pop(choicetwo)
            if len(samples) == 0:
                q = random.choice(a)
                samples.append(q)
        if choice == "+":
            q = random.choice(a)
            samples.append(q)
        if choice == "r.c":
            choicetwo = random.randint(0,len(samples))
            if choicetwo == len(samples):
                choicetwo -= 1
            samples.pop(choicetwo)
            samples.insert(choicetwo,random.choice(a))
    if l == 'a':
        if it > max:
            it = 0
            print "oh"

        if it < max:
            it += 1
            it1 = it - 1
            c = samples[it1:it1 + 1]
            print "Ok"
    loop()

def loop():

    global a
    global Ai
    global Player
    global l
    global c
    global play

    b = raw_input("R, P, or S? :")
    b = b.upper()

    if b != "R" and b != "P" and b != "S":
        loop()

    elif b == "R" and c == "S":
        print "Rock .VS. Scissors"
        print "You win!"
        Player += 1
        l = 'p'
    elif b == "R" and c == "P":
        print "Rock .VS. Paper"
        print "You lose!"
        Ai += 1
        l = 'a'
    elif b == c:
        print "Tie!"
        l = 'p'
    elif b == "R" and c == "R":
        # Just for errors
        print "Tie!"
        l = 'p'

    elif b == "P" and c == "R":
        print "Paper .VS. Rock"
        print "You win!"
        Player += 1
        l = 'p'
    elif b == "P" and c == "S":
        print "Paper .VS. Scissors"
        print "You lose!"
        Ai += 1
        l = 'a'
    elif b == "S" and c == "R":
        print "Scissors .VS. Rock"
        print "You lose!"
        Ai += 1
        l = 'a'
    elif b == "S" and c == "P":
        print "Scissors .VS. Paper"
        print "You win!"
        Player +=1
        l = 'p'

    print ""
    print "Ai: " + str(Ai) + ", Player: " + str(Player)
    print ""
    play += 1

    learn()
loop()
```

Comment: Hint: you can think of R, P, S as three points in a circle instead of doing so many if else. give them 1,2 and 3 score respectively. then just subtract ai score from you. try it on paper, you should see the solution.

Comment: Sorry to ask, what exactly do you mean by that?